# How to use link_to inside a nested form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a nested form for an object that may contain many files. I don't have a problem in the creation of the object but when I need to edit it, I found out the problem, form should have a link for the file url but I don't know how to reference the file itself. I'm using paperclip. In this case IF there was only one file and it was in the object model I would do something like @object.file.url but since there are many files, I don't know how to proceed in this case...

**edit.html.haml**

```
= form_for @object, :url => { :action => "update", :controller => "object", :id => @object.id, :method => "post" }, :html => { :multipart => true }  do |f|

  - render "object/object_form", object: f.object, f: f
```

**object_form.html.haml**

```
.field
  = f.label :name
  = f.text_field :name

= f.fields_for :files do |builder|
  = render 'object/file_fields', :f => builder
%p= link_to_add_fields "Add new file", f, :file

.field
  = f.submit "Save"
```

**file_fields.html.haml**

```
%fieldset
  .field
    = f.label :file
    = f.file_field :file
  .field
    = f.hidden_field :_destroy
    = link_to "Remove File", '#', class: "remove_fields"
```

**What I'm trying to do that obviously doesn't work in file_fields.html.haml**

```
%fieldset
  .field
    = f.label :file
    = f.file_field :file
    = link_to f.file.url 
  .field
    = f.hidden_field :_destroy
    = link_to "Remove File", '#', class: "remove_fields"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do

```
f.object.url
```

So:

```
%fieldset
  .field
    = f.label :file
    = f.file_field :file
    # Not sure if it would produce a Nil error on the new form.
    # given how the f object wouldn't yet have a url
    - if f.object.url
       = link_to f.object.url 
  .field
    = f.hidden_field :_destroy
    = link_to "Remove File", '#', class: "remove_fields"
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right... f.object did the trick, however, to get the url is f.object.file.url! =)